# Problema con Joomla y su visualización en tablets modo horizontal

Tags: joomla3

Buenos días.

Tengo un problema con mi web y la forma en la que se muestra en las tabletas en modo horizontal, he buscado en google pero no consigo encontrar la solución exacta.

Esta es mi web (no esta terminada, faltan muchos detalles por pulir)

www.valencianadesierras.com

El problema que tengo es que en las tablets como por ejemplo ipad2 al ponerla en modo horizontal es como si pasara a ser la versión de escritorio de la web.

No seria mucho problema si no fuera porque como veréis el top menú no cabe en la pantalla de la tableta y lo pone en una linea aparte descuadrándose.

Quisiera saber si existe algún codigo que le pueda añadir al template para que el top menú no se muestre en el modo horizontal de la tableta y dejar solo el off canvas menu del lateral.

Si no es posible otra solución valida para mi seria forzar la misma vista responsive que se muestra en horizontal pero en vertical.

Según lo que llevo leído creo que para esto debería cambiar los parámetros en el fichero responsive.less para forzar una vista u otra según la resolución de la pantalla, pero los códigos que llevo probados hasta ahora no me han servido.

No se si me he explicado bien, agradecería un poco de ayuda porque ya me tiene un poco desesperado.

Gracias, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la respuesta para ocultar el top menu y dejar solo el off-canvas en la tableta modo horizontal, al menos a mi me ha funcionado aunque aun sigo testando por si acaso, la dejo aquí por si a alguien le sirve de ayuda.

En el backend de joomla ir a;

Templates > tu template > Layout > Pestaña Menu.

Poner solo la opción Mega Menu en Menu Type.

Ahora hay que editar el archivo menu.php que debería estar en:

tusitio.com/templates/tutemplate/features/menu.php

Hay que buscar esta linea:

```
<?php $this->helix3->loadMegaMenu('hidden-xs'); ?>
```

Y dejarla así:

```
<?php $this->helix3->loadMegaMenu('hidden-xs hidden-sm hidden-md'); ?>
```

Y con esto debería bastar.

Saludos.